# Reverse string in malloc

Tags: c, string, malloc, strcpy, strcat

I need define a “word” in this question to be any sequence of characters that doesn’t contain a space or null character.
For example, the string `“Hello World”` would contain 2 words. However, it is actually possible for a word to be empty
i.e., zero chars.
A sentence would be a series of words that are separated by 1 space character. So `“Hello World”` would be a
sentence of two words. The goal of `ReverseSentence` would be to reverse the sentence in terms of word.
Right now, I am having an error whereby programs proceed to call function and prints out a1 to a5. Upon reaching a5, it seems that program abort and core dumped. If i replace blank with space, it will read in the previous input and replace according to number of space.
Where am i going wrong?

**ReverseSentence.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>  /* malloc */
#include <string.h>  /* strcat, strcpy */

void ReverseSentence(char *str)
{
    char *newSentence;
    int i, j, start, len;
    /* contains the string length of the input */
    len = strlen(str);
    /* position or index in the array */
    start = strlen(str);
    /* malloc */
    newSentence = malloc(len + 1);

    /* loop checks from the right of the sentences */
    for (i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
        /* if index reach the array with a space or zero */
        if (str[i] == ' ' || i == 0) {
            /* allocates memory */
            char *word = malloc((start - i) + 1);
            int c = 0;

            if (i == 0) 
                /* index remains same */
                j = i;
            else
                j = i + 1;

            /* j smaller or equal than the start position */
            for (; j <= start; j++) {
                /*do a incremental*/
                word[c++] = str[j];
            }
            /* hits a null char */
            word[c] = '\0';
            /* string concatenate */
            strcat(newSentence, word);
            /* if index hits a space */
            if (str[i] == ' ')
                strcat(newSentence, " "); /* concatenate space to newSentence */
            else
                strcat(newSentence, "\0");
            start = i - 1;

            /* free memory */
            free(word);
        }
    }
    newSentence[len] = '\0';
    /* string copy */
    /* str is destination, newSentence is the source */
    /* copy new string to original string */
    strcpy(str, newSentence);
    /* free memory */
    free(newSentence);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ReverseSentence.h"

int main()
{
    char a1[] = "Hello World ";
    char a2[] = "abcdefghi ";
    char a3[] = " ";
    char a4[] = "C programming is a dangerous activity";
    char a5[] = "a "; /* a sentence with only empty words */
    ReverseSentence(a1);

    printf("Test case 1:\"%s\"\n", a1); /* prints "World Hello" */
    ReverseSentence(a2);

    printf("Test case 2:\"%s\"\n", a2); /* prints "abcdefghi" */
    ReverseSentence(a3);

    printf("Test case 3:\"%s\"\n", a3); /* prints "" */

    ReverseSentence(a4);
    printf("Test case 4:\"%s\"\n", a4); /* prints "activity dangerous a is pro Cgramming" */

    ReverseSentence(a5);
    printf("Test case 5:\"%s\"\n", a5); /* prints " " */

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: new version**

```
void ReverseSentence(char *str)
{
    /* holder */
    /* pointer to char */
    char *newSentence;
    int i, start, len, lastindex, size;

    /* contains the string length of the input */
    len = strlen(str);
    lastindex = strlen(str);
    /* starting position */
    start = 0;
    i = 0;
    /* malloc */
    newSentence = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str));

    while (i >= 0) {
        for (i = len - 1; str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != ' '; i--) {
            lastindex--;
        }

        /* number of chars in string size */
        size = len - lastindex;
        /* Copy word into newStr at startMarker */
        strncpy(&newSentence[start], &str[lastindex], size);

        /* pointer move to right */
        start = start + size;
        /* Space placed into memory slot */
        newSentence[start] = ' ';
        /* start position moves by 1 towards the right */
        start = start + 1;
        /* pointer at len moves to left */
        lastindex = lastindex - 1;
        /* lastindex moves to where len is */
        len = lastindex;
    }

    /* Copy new string into old string */
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        str[i] = newSentence[i];
    }

    /* free memory */
    free(newSentence);
}
```

Comment: reads array from right to left, then strcat the word after the check hits the space, then copy the string to new string

Comment: Here it already crashes with a1.

Comment: There is at least one issue in your new version: `newSentence = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str) )`. You don't allocate enough memory, you don't account for the zero terminator. You should allocate one more byte. But there are other issues. BTW: `sizeof(char)` is always `1` per definition, so you don't need to write it.

Comment: I reverted the last edit: do not overwrite the original post as it makes the discussion inconsistent, added the new version at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not safe. You never initialize `newSentence`, since `malloc()` only allocates but not initialize the memory (in contrast to `calloc()`). Thus, you are starting with a garbage sentence, where you append something new (`strcat()`). Depending on the garbage, there may be no 0 even in the allocated memory, and you access some unallocated memory area.

Comment: Not only it's not safe, it's wrong. You _must_ initialize the `newSentence` buffer after the call to `malloc`, e.g `newSentence[0] = 0`.

Comment: @michael Walz 
Got it. I came out with another solution. will be editing my post on top

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Matthias' answer: you don't allocate enough memory, I just did a wild guess and added 1 to the arguments passed to `malloc`.

```
newSentence = malloc(len + 2);   // +2 instead of +1
```

and

```
char *word = malloc((start - i) + 2);  // +2 instead of +1
```

And now it doesn't crash anymore. So there is definitely a buffer overflow here.

I don't pretend the program is perfectly correct now. You should have a look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is too complicated. It has several issues:

- you do not initialize `newSentence`: since `malloc` memory is uninitialized, you invoke undefined behavior when you copy the words at its end with `strcat`. You can fix that with `*newSentence = '\0';`
- when you copy the word into the allocated `word` buffer, you iterate upto and including `start`, then you add a `'\0'` at the end.  You effectively write one byte too many for the last word (case `i == 0`).  This invokes undefined behavior.
- `strcat(newSentence, "\0");` does nothing.
- allocating a buffer for each word found is wasteful, you could just copy the word with `memcpy` or with a simple `for` loop.

You could simplify with the following steps:

- allocate a buffer and copy the string to it.
- for each word in the string, copy it at the end of the destination and copy the separator before it if not at the end.
- free the buffer.

Here is the code:

```
char *ReverseSentence(char *str) {
    int len = strlen(tmp);    /* length of the string */
    char *tmp = strdup(str);  /* copy of the string */
    int i;        /* index into the copy */
    int j = len;  /* index into the string */
    int n;        /* length of a word */
    for (i = 0; i < len; ) {
        n = strcspn(tmp + i, " ");   /* n is the length of the word */
        j -= n;                      /* adjust destination offset */
        memcpy(str + j, tmp + i, n); /* copy the word */
        i += n;                      /* skip the word */
        if (tmp[i] != '\0') {        /* unless we are at the end */
            j--;
            str[j] = tmp[i];         /* copy the separator */
            i++;
        }
    }
    free(tmp);                       /* free the copy */
    return str;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I came out with another solution. will be editing my post on top.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues in the new version of your program:

- You don't allocate enough memory, you don't account for the zero terminator. You should allocate one more byte.
- in your first `for` loop you allow `i` to become -1. The loop should stop when `i` is zero: modify your `for` statement like this: `for(i=len-1; tr[i] != ' ' && i >= 0; i--)`. You incorrecty assume that the first byte before the `str` buffer is zero, therefore the `str[i]!='\0'` is wrong. BTW accessing one byte before the `str` buffer yields in undefined behaviour.
- There are probably other issues.